# Capybara, finding within a css element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I'm working with Ruby on Rails 3, Cucumber, and Capybara

I've been searching for quite some time, and I can't figure out how to find a specific page element within a css tag. In my case, I need to make sure that a name is found inside of a table, and not in the "Welcome [Name]".

I tried something like:

```
within('table') do
  page.body.index("[Name]")
end
```

And I have a table with `id='table'`.

But I'd like to know how to do this for any css element, such as:

```
within('h2') do
  page.body.should have_content ('stuff')
end
```

I think my problem has to do with page.body, but I'm not sure how to contain it to a particular css tag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Capybara's `within` matcher only matches the first result, so if you have multiple `h2` tags, it'll only look in the first one.

Instead, try `have_css` with the `:text` option.

```
page.should have_css("#table", :text => "[Name]")
page.should have_css('h2', :text => 'stuff')
```

Comment: This works, would there be a good way to get the index of that found element? So if I wanted to compare the order of two elements in a table, I think the best way would be to find the index of each, and compare them.

Answer (score 12):

To find a specific element:

```
page.find('#table').should have_text('stuff')
```

Comment: have_text is no longer supported. Use page.find("#table").should have_content('stuff') instead.

Answer (score 4):

I guess all answers should work but now Capybara doesn't use should anymore it uses expect

```
expect(page).to have_css("#table", :text => "[Name]")
expect(page).to have_css('h2', :text => 'stuff')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done stuff like this:
`page.all(:css, 'button.btn-primary.days.active').size.should == 1`

To check if there are any elements that contain a specific set of classes.
I didn't need to look for a particular text value of the element though. 
I just wanted to ensure the existence of the element, and how many of them there were.