# Cucumber - Capybara search for text within table row

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-table, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to search within a single table row for my cucumber test.

I have each row formatted like this:

```
%tr
  %td= title
  %td= complete
  %td= goal
```

And I am looking to search within a row with a given title, and check the goal

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles on this question, I think a better way to do this is:

```
find('tr', text: 'My title').should have_content(goal)
```

This way you're not adding a title attribute when it's not really needed

Comment: This is also allowed: `within find('tr', text: 'My title') { click_link 'edit' }`

Answer (score 2):

I would probably add an attribute to the `td` you're interested in. Do something like:

```
%tr
  %td{title= "#{title}"}= title
  %td= complete
  %td= goal
```

Then you can refer to this question on StackOverflow about finding within a specific element using css.

[Capybara, finding within a css element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158328/capybara-finding-within-a-css-element)

Comment: That's basically what I ended up doing - I added an id to the table row, and then used this for my test: 
page.find("##{my_code}").should have_content(goal)